# Computed column, or update column by trigger to keep statistics

Tags: .net, sql-server, calculated-columns

For every user, our application calculates some statistics, like how many times they logged in or how many answers they got wrong in the quiz, ... it can be all sorts of things. The app runs on SQL Server and .NET Entity Framework 6.1

Right now, the statistics are calculated on demand but as the user base grows, this makes the reporting part of the application ever slower.

We were wondering about either using computed columns (either persisted or not persisted) or use a trigger to store these values with the user.

How would you go about doing this? It seems to me that computed columns may be easier to implement, but they would get recalculated every time I read the User from the table, which may not be very much faster than what we're doing now. Since we would fit an entire SQL query into the computed column, persisting the column does not seem a right fit either (how will SQL Server deduce that it should update the calculation?).
A trigger on certain actions seems to be a more logical fit for me.

For the sake of the argument, suppose all the calculated statistics are `count(*)` and `sum(*)` of values in other tables and nothing more interesting than that.

Comment: __how many times they logged in__ : this is a constantly evolving number, while __how many answers they got wrong in the quiz__ appears to be a static number once "the quiz" is completed. So you really have 2 very different situations and will likely need different approaches.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment, but they were just two stupid examples. In reality they are all constantly changing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to store computed values, prefer to have the SQL Engine do the work for you rather than manually implementing this via triggers.

So, that would be persisted [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) and/or [indexed views](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864(v=sql.105).aspx).

> they would get recalculated every time I read the User from the table

Only if you *include* the computed column in your `SELECT` (and you've not opted for it to be persisted). This is why queries should generally only query for the columns that are required, rather than `select *`. However, since you're using an ORM, you may not be able to tell it not to include an expensive column - that's why you should prefer persistence or to use an indexed view - so that it's treated as a separate object that you load only when needed.

> how will SQL Server deduce that it should update the calculation?

Because behind the scenes, SQL Server effectively implements triggers itself. But the bonus here is, those triggers have been tested millions of times and are code you don't have to write.

> For the sake of the argument, suppose all the calculated statistics are `count(*)` and `sum(*)` of values in other tables

In such a circumstance, you can't really go the computed column route (computed columns should only really reference their own row in their own table. There are some quirky ways to try and bypass this using UDFs, but I'd usually recommend against), so in this case, I'd definitely be recommending the indexed view.

Answer (score 0):

> For the sake of the argument, suppose all the calculated statistics are count(*) and sum(*) of values and nothing more interesting than that.

Since your operations for reporting are simple enough, I'd recommend a reporting table/audit log table for these statistics.

Basic premise is that all reports can be obtained as a variation of a simple query like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUserLog (NO LOCK) WHERE UserID=34
```

or in a slightly complex query like

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY colB) as Metric1, 
  SUM(*) OVER (PARTITION BY colD ORDER BY colC) as Metric2
FROM tblUserLog (NO LOCK) WHERE UserID =34
```

Main problem is now **how to populate this table** `tblUserLog` and **what should be the composition**.

***Composition***:

The schema of of the tables should be generic and must satisfy all your reporting needs like columns to count on or sum on. Say something on the lines of

```
LogID (PK, auto increment)
LogDateTimestamp
LogType
UserID
MetricToSum1
MetricToSum2
....
```

This is rather de-normalized table; and I would not recommend normalizing it.

**How to populate:**

This should definitely not be done via triggers. Looking at the best possible alternatives, and assuming that your web application has a well tiered architecture; you should have a log method in place which can insert into the DB table necessary details ***asynchronously***. So basically writing on the table happens asynchronously along with the main user table CRUD and reading on demand 
whenever report are needed.

For a very simple operations I would suggest you to simply implement a view over the main entity table like User. An example of this sort be a view which returns say the count of active users for admin reporting.